# What will happen if i initialize multiple object context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I wanted to know what will happen if i initialize multiple object context ,multiple times , how does entity framework manages connections.
Would the below code create three new connections to the db or only one connection can any one let know thanks in advance.

```
using (MDDXITEntities context = new MDDXITEntities())
{
    userData= context.uspGetuserData(userID).ToList();

    using (MDDXITEntities context1 = new MDDXITEntities())
    {
       userData = context1.uspGetuserData(userID).ToList();
    }

    using (MDDXITEntities context2 = new MDDXITEntities())
    {
        userData = context2.uspGetuserData(userID).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened when you did?

Comment: EF has its own way of managing connection pool. Your code will create three new connections.

Comment: Nothing happens, but i wanted know whether entity frame work opens multiple connections to the db or only one connection

Comment: Is there a difference between having opened one or three connections? You will close them in the end of the `using` anyway

Comment: @Fabio More likely return them to the pool, but yeah, basically the same thing.

Comment: Ok guys thanks, but would it create any issue if i use multiple using blocks would i get any error if i use 100 using and another questions would i run into concurrency-related issues if i use only one instance at the class level   MDDXITEntities context2 = new MDDXITEntities() and use it every were

Answer (score 0):

It repeats the DB operation Multiple times.

Your are Targeting Only One Connection with multiple Objects

Like DB is same

objects are different

```
context --->DB
context1 -->DB
context2 -->DB
```

like this.

Comment: Ok , but would it create any issue if i use multiple using blocks would i get any error if i use 100 using and another questions would i run into concurrency-related issues if i use only one instance at the class level MDDXITEntities context2 = new MDDXITEntities() and use it every were